# Error in match.arg(what) : 'arg' should be one of “median”, “mean”

Tags: r, imputation

I'm trying to impute missing values in the Year_of_Release variable using the with() and impute() functions in R , but i get this error : Error in match.arg(what) : 'arg' should be one of “median”, “mean”.
below are my libraries and the code:

```
#Libraries used:
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(reshape2)
library(Hmisc)
library(mctest)
library(rpart)
library(e1071)
library(caTools)
library(rpart.plot)
library(neuralnet)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(rattle)
library(graphics)
library(missForest)
library(VIM)
library(caret)
library(ggplot2)
library(fmsb)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(babynames)
library(kernlab)
library(scales)

#Phase One: Data Preprocessing:
#Loading in the "vgsales.csv" data:
game_sales <- read.csv("vgsales.csv", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

#turning the structure of the data to tibble for ease of use:
game_sales <- as_tibble(game_sales)

#Replacing the "N/A" character values in Year_of_Release with real NA values:
game_sales %>% filter(game_sales$Year_of_Release == "N/A")
game_sales <- game_sales %>% mutate( Year_of_Release = gsub("N/A","", Year_of_Release))

#Changing the data type of column Year_of_release from "chr" to "int":
game_sales$Year_of_Release <- as.integer(game_sales$Year_of_Release)

#Imputing Year_of_Release variable and inserting the imputed values:
imputeyear <- with(game_sales,impute(game_sales$Year_of_Release, 'random'))
game_sales <- game_sales %>% mutate (Year_of_Release = imputeyear)
```

Comment: You don't need `game_sales$` when you are using `with`

Comment: Of the 24 packages you include in your question, which one does `impute` come from? (Have a look at the `?impute` help page if you're unsure--it should state it.)

Comment: you mean i should write it like so ```imputeyear <- with(game_sales,impute(Year_of_Release, 'random'))``` ?

Comment: Your error message says `impute` has 2 possible values for that argument—median and mean—but you've instead given it "random". Maybe check the docs for wherever this function comes from

Comment: @Gregor this impute() function is part of the Hmisc library.

Comment: @camillie i had this same code running and functioning well before, it is possible to impute using random values, but it suddenly started giving me this error, i don't know what has changed.

Comment: Well, you also show `library(e1071)`, and that package [has an impute function with no "random" option](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/e1071/versions/1.7-9/topics/impute). You can fix by specifying `Hmisc::impute(...)` in your code.

Comment: Gregor, you awesome :D you did it ! thank you buddy, i need the e1071 library for further use down the road in my code, thanks for teaching me this trick.  by the way, my local machine is so slow, i can't run my machine learning algorithms on it , could you kindly advise on that ? thanks again

Comment: If your computer is too slow, use one on the cloud. RStudio Connect, AWS, Azure, GCP, Digital Ocean... plenty of options.

Answer (score 0):

You've masked `Hmisc::impute` with `e1071::impute`, which has no "random" option. You can fix by specifying Hmisc::impute(...) in your code.

You can make problems like this more rare by making your scripts smaller (e.g., separate scripts for loading, cleaning, and modeling data), and not loading unnecessary packages. If you only need one or two functions one or two times, use `::` instead of loading the whole package. And be aware of what comes from where. `tidyverse` already loads `dplyr`, `tidyr`, `stringr`, `ggplot2`. Hopefully `tidyr` should mean you don't need `reshape2`. `graphics` is part of base R and loaded by default.